# Flexbox - "space-between" - Zero width elements cause unwanted spaces

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a kind of "glossary" with flexbox elements. I have a navigation to scroll to the right letter.

There is my Problem:
I placed anchor-links before the first element of each letter. This causes unwanted spaces even if the elements has got width:0px; visibility:hidden; etc. I guess I've tried nearly everything... Hope you've got a solution.

Notice: In this case it is not an option to set the anchor-link to position:absolute!

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.letters {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px
}

.letters ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 34px;
 line-height: 34px;
 list-style: outside none none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 34px;
 margin: 0 .27em;
}

.letters ul li a {
 background: #ad1800 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #ad1800;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 line-height: 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.letter_around {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 50px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
 -moz-justify-content: space-between;
 justify-content: space-between;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.glossary_item {
 padding: 15px 20px 20px;
 width: 22%;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 transition: 0.4s all;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.glossary_letter {
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper glossary_wrapper">
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="letters clearfix">
      <ul class="letters_ul">
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#B">B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#C">C</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#D">D</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#E">E</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="letter_around">
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="A" name="A"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="B" name="B"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="C" name="C"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">C - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="D" name="D"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="E" name="E"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the unwanted space!! be clear?

Comment: You don't need `.glossary-letter` to be an anchor tag. For semantics, consider using a `span` instead. Why is `position: absolute` not possible here?

Comment: @rahulmr: The Spaces are before every first box of a new letter. So you have got "<space> A A A <space> B B B B B B <space> C <space> D D D <space> E E E". Look at thesnippet and you will see

Comment: @ovokuro: Well, I need an element to scroll to. If it's a span or an A-Tag doesn't matter at this problem. position: absolute would cause a problem, that the anchors will be places on the top of the wrapper. And I can't wrap every letter, because the flexbox would be cutted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my own. It's not the best solution I guess, but it works fine.

I filled the spaces calculated by flexbox itself with a margin-left minus value of the percentage that is left. So in my Case the widht of the elements was 22%. This 4x is 88% of the whole container width. That means that the calculated margin of the elements is about 4% of the container width. So if you reduce the margin of the anchor-element by 4% you get the right position of the boxes.

I know that is not the best solution, but it works. If you've got a better one, please show me. :)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.letters {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px
}

.letters ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 34px;
 line-height: 34px;
 list-style: outside none none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 34px;
 margin: 0 .27em;
}

.letters ul li a {
 background: #ad1800 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #ad1800;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 line-height: 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.letter_around {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
 -moz-justify-content: space-between;
 justify-content: space-between;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.glossary_item {
 padding: 15px 20px 20px;
 width: 22%;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 transition: 0.4s all;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.glossary_letter {
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper glossary_wrapper">
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="letters clearfix">
      <ul class="letters_ul">
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#B">B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#C">C</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#D">D</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#E">E</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="letter_around">
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="A" name="A"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="B" name="B"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="C" name="C"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">C - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="D" name="D"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="E" name="E"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not particularly clean. Ideally, someone with more knowledge will provide a better solution.

1. Remove `justify-content` property from `.letter-around`
2. Add `margin-right: auto` to `glossary-item` to create space between the items.
3. Target the last item in each grid using `nth-of-type` selector, and remove the margin.

I have changed the `glossary-letter` from `a` to a `span`, I think it makes more sense semantically. I have also moved some of the css rules from `.glossary-item` to the `span`.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.letters {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.letters ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin: 0 .27em;
}

.letters ul li a {
  background: #ad1800 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ad1800;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.letter_around {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.glossary_item {
  transition: 0.4s all;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 22%;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.glossary_item span {
  padding: 15px 20px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
}

.glossary_item:nth-of-type(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper glossary_wrapper">
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="letters clearfix">
      <ul class="letters_ul">
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#B">B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#C">C</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#D">D</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#E">E</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="letter_around">
      <span class="glossary_letter" id="A" name="A"></span>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <span class="glossary_letter" id="B" name="B"></span>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <span class="glossary_letter" id="C" name="C"></span>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">C - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <span class="glossary_letter" id="D" name="D"></span>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <span class="glossary_letter" id="E" name="E"></span>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just use `margin:auto` for `.glossary_item` and `margin:0` for `glossary_letter`. I believe it should be the accepted solution then!

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Thanks for input. I can't get `margin: 0` to work in this case, do you have a demo?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to add

```
.glossary_letter {
  display: none;
}
```

So it fisically will be but your extra space will disappear.

Comment: Yeah that is a simple solution, but this causes that the anchor has no functionality. So it's not what I need for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try another way, it keeps the anchor link working:

```
.glossary_letter {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, the functionality is there, but the spaces are still there too...

Comment: @F.Esser it's really strange: I've tried this solution with your code - and gap disappered

Comment: This fixes the space issue, but it sets a kind of break between the letters. Thats not the behavior the elements should have, you know?
I just want to delete the spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Setting `justify-content: space-around` is basically the same as setting `auto` to left and right margins to *all* flex items (the available space will be distributed equally on the left and on the right of each of them). So, to exclude some items from available space distribution, you can remove `justify-content` and set the equivalent margins only to the needed items:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.letters {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px
}

.letters ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 34px;
 line-height: 34px;
 list-style: outside none none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 34px;
 margin: 0 .27em;
}

.letters ul li a {
 background: #ad1800 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #ad1800;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 line-height: 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.letter_around {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 50px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.glossary_item {
 padding: 15px 20px 20px;
 width: 22%;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 transition: 0.4s all;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.glossary_letter {
 width: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper glossary_wrapper">
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="letters clearfix">
      <ul class="letters_ul">
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#B">B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#C">C</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#D">D</a>
        </li>
        <li class="glossarylink">
          <a href="#E">E</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="letter_around">
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="A" name="A"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">A - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="B" name="B"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">B - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="C" name="C"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">C - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="D" name="D"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">D - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <a class="glossary_letter" id="E" name="E"></a>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
      <div class="glossary_item"><span class="glossary-title">E - Lorem ipsum dolor </span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```